# How to compare two iterators for unit test on VS2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-c++

code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace unit_test
{
    TEST_CLASS(test_iterator)
    {
    public:

        TEST_METHOD(vector_with_int)
        {
            std::vector<int> samples;
            Assert::AreEqual(samples.begin(), samples.begin());
        }

    };
}
```

When compiling :

> Error  1   error C2338: Test writer must define specialization of ToString for your class class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString > >>(const class std::_Vector_iterator > > &).  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\unittest\include\cppunittestassert.h 66  1   unit_test

How to fix this problem? Should I use another framework instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to subtract `begin` from each iterator (if they're random iterators) so you're comparing `size_type` offsets rather than iterator types:

```
Assert::AreEqual(samples.begin() - samples.begin(), samples.begin() - samples.begin());
```

Comment: +1 for suggestion. Pretty sure this way works. Just wondering is there another way to compare `iterator` directly? Or another framework that is able to do this job?

Comment: @YueWang pretty sure [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) can handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Just add something like this before your tests:

```
namespace Microsoft { namespace VisualStudio { namespace CppUnitTestFramework {

   using vecint_itr = typename std::vector<int>::iterator;

   template<> inline std::wstring ToString<vecint_itr>(vecint_itr const & t)
   {
      return L"vecint_itr"; // replace with string with whatever you like
   }

}}}
```

This injects a ToString function into the CppUnitTestFramework, which is needed to convert your iterator into a string value that can be displayed by the testing framework. This is exactly what the error message is asking you to do.